# Simulating Aquatic Environments

Tags: gazebo-2.2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to create a simple beach environment for Gazebo. Is there a way for me to simulate shallow water? I just want to robot to drive down the "sand" and look like it's partially submerged in water.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6899/simulating-aquatic-environments/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you only want the robot to disappear, then you can create a blue box model that has a visual and no collision. There will be no physical interaction between the robot and the water this way.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-09-02**:
When you say "blue visual" do you mean just a blue colored plane with no collision component?